# How to implement HashMap with two keys?

Tags: hashmap, rust

`HashMap` implements the `get` and `insert` methods which take a single immutable borrow and a single move of a value respectively.

I want a trait which is just like this but which takes two keys instead of one. It uses the map inside, but it's just a detail of implementation.

```
pub struct Table<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> {
    map: HashMap<(A, B), f64>,
}

impl<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> Memory<A, B> for Table<A, B> {
    fn get(&self, a: &A, b: &B) -> f64 {
        let key: &(A, B) = ??;
        *self.map.get(key).unwrap()
    }

    fn set(&mut self, a: A, b: B, v: f64) {
        self.map.insert((a, b), v);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what problem are you facing?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around how do I take the two borrows and make a borrowed tuple. Or how to turn &A and &B into &(A, B), which is what I need to `.get` the hashmap

Comment: It will be easier for people to help you if you show what you tried and what errors or problems you encountered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think you can because the `(A,B)` tuple requires its elements to be next to each other in memory, whereas your `&A` and `&B` may be stored anywhere. You will need to use `Copy`able or `Clone`able keys so you can duplicate them as needed, or remove the references and move them inside your `get` function.

Comment: The borrow checker is lurking behind what you are trying to do: While you have borrows on `A` and `B` individually, neither the caller nor the hashmap is not going to keep ownership of the tuple `(&A, &B)`. If you construct the tuple yourself and use a reference to that, nobody is holding ownership while the tuple is referenced by the map. Long story short: You can't. Construct map for `&(&A, &B)` directly and have the caller construct the tuples, instead of trying to use two individual keys.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is certainly possible. The [signature of `get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) is

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> 
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

The problem here is to implement a `&Q` type such that

1. `(A, B): Borrow<Q>`
2. `Q` implements `Hash + Eq`

To satisfy condition (1), we need to think of how to write

```
fn borrow(self: &(A, B)) -> &Q
```

The trick is that `&Q` *does not need to be a simple pointer*, it can be a [trait object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567849/what-makes-something-a-trait-object)! The idea is to create a trait `Q` which will have two implementations:

```
impl Q for (A, B)
impl Q for (&A, &B)
```

The `Borrow` implementation will simply return `self` and we can construct a `&dyn Q` trait object from the two elements separately.

---

The [full implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fa1d88a3f3255fa7a6ca39dee02da4d8) is like this:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

// See explanation (1).
trait KeyPair<A, B> {
    /// Obtains the first element of the pair.
    fn a(&self) -> &A;
    /// Obtains the second element of the pair.
    fn b(&self) -> &B;
}

// See explanation (2).
impl<'a, A, B> Borrow<dyn KeyPair<A, B> + 'a> for (A, B)
where
    A: Eq + Hash + 'a,
    B: Eq + Hash + 'a,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &(dyn KeyPair<A, B> + 'a) {
        self
    }
}

// See explanation (3).
impl<A: Hash, B: Hash> Hash for dyn KeyPair<A, B> + '_ {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.a().hash(state);
        self.b().hash(state);
    }
}

impl<A: Eq, B: Eq> PartialEq for dyn KeyPair<A, B> + '_ {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.a() == other.a() && self.b() == other.b()
    }
}

impl<A: Eq, B: Eq> Eq for dyn KeyPair<A, B> + '_ {}

// OP's Table struct
pub struct Table<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> {
    map: HashMap<(A, B), f64>,
}

impl<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> Table<A, B> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Table {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, a: &A, b: &B) -> f64 {
        *self.map.get(&(a, b) as &dyn KeyPair<A, B>).unwrap()
    }

    fn set(&mut self, a: A, b: B, v: f64) {
        self.map.insert((a, b), v);
    }
}

// Boring stuff below.

impl<A, B> KeyPair<A, B> for (A, B) {
    fn a(&self) -> &A {
        &self.0
    }
    fn b(&self) -> &B {
        &self.1
    }
}
impl<A, B> KeyPair<A, B> for (&A, &B) {
    fn a(&self) -> &A {
        self.0
    }
    fn b(&self) -> &B {
        self.1
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct A(&'static str);

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct B(&'static str);

fn main() {
    let mut table = Table::new();
    table.set(A("abc"), B("def"), 4.0);
    table.set(A("123"), B("456"), 45.0);
    println!("{:?} == 45.0?", table.get(&A("123"), &B("456")));
    println!("{:?} == 4.0?", table.get(&A("abc"), &B("def")));
    // Should panic below.
    println!("{:?} == NaN?", table.get(&A("123"), &B("def")));
}
```

Explanation:

1. The `KeyPair` trait takes the role of `Q` we mentioned above. We'd need to `impl Eq + Hash for dyn KeyPair`, but `Eq` and `Hash` are both not [object safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096235/understanding-traits-and-object-safety). We add the `a()` and `b()` methods to help implementing them manually.
2. Now we implement the `Borrow` trait from `(A, B)` to `dyn KeyPair + 'a`. Note the `'a` — this is a subtle bit that is needed to make `Table::get` actually work. The arbitrary `'a` allows us to say that an `(A, B)` can be borrowed to the trait object for *any* lifetime. If we don't specify the `'a`, the unsized trait object will [default to `'static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212397/references-to-traits-in-structs), meaning the `Borrow` trait can only be applied when the implementation like `(&A, &B)` outlives `'static`, which is certainly not the case.
3. Finally, we implement `Eq` and `Hash`. Same reason as point 2, we implement for `dyn KeyPair + '_` instead of `dyn KeyPair` (which means `dyn KeyPair + 'static` in this context). The `'_` here is a syntax sugar meaning arbitrary lifetime.

---

Using trait objects will incur indirection cost when computing the hash and checking equality in `get()`. The cost can be eliminated if the optimizer is able to devirtualize that, but whether LLVM will do it is unknown.

An alternative is to store the map as `HashMap<(Cow<A>, Cow<B>), f64>`. Using this requires less "clever code", but there is now a memory cost to store the owned/borrowed flag as well as runtime cost in both `get()` and `set()`.

Unless you fork the standard `HashMap` and add a method to look up an entry via `Hash + Eq` alone, there is no guaranteed-zero-cost solution.

Comment: I'm stunned on how complete and detailed this answer was. After reading it three times (that's on Rust, not you), I think I get it. Yeah, I thought I was missing something but it turns out the problem was kind of tricky. Many many thanks.

Comment: yeah, mad props. This is a great answer to the question, but also a great example for beginners of how to leverage and understand Rust's trait system

Comment: A slightly confusing point is that line 14 (`impl Borrow for (A, B)`) actually covers both `(A, B)` and `(&A, &B)`. I was trying to port this solution to a similar problem where I am using `struct Foo([T; 2])` as the key type instead, and I needed to impl Borrow for both `Foo` and `(&T, &T)` separately. This was actually explained in (2), but I missed that at first and took a while to notice.

Comment: Another note is that, as of Rust 1.56.0-nightly (2021-07-31), if you miss the `+ '_` behind the `Hash` or `Eq` impl, you get the error `explicit lifetime required in the type of b` on line 53, annotating `self.map.get` with `lifetime 'static required` without pointing to the correct place. This is quite confusing since we didn't explicitly mention `'static` anywhere in the code, but is implied by the `dyn`.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete or fails when A & B are String, but you try to use `&(&str, &str)` with `HashMap::get()`.  Then the compiler complains about unimplemented trait bounds.

Answer (score 3):

A `Memory` trait that take two keys, *set* by value and *get* by reference:

```
trait Memory<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> {

    fn get(&self, a: &A, b: &B) -> Option<&f64>;

    fn set(&mut self, a: A, b: B, v: f64);
}
```

You can `impl` such trait using a Map of Maps:

```
pub struct Table<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> {
    table: HashMap<A, HashMap<B, f64>>,
}   

impl<A: Eq + Hash, B: Eq + Hash> Memory<A, B> for Table<A, B> {

    fn get(&self, a: &A, b: &B) -> Option<&f64> {
        self.table.get(a)?.get(b)
    }

    fn set(&mut self, a: A, b: B, v: f64) {
        let inner = self.table.entry(a).or_insert(HashMap::new());
        inner.insert(b, v);
    }
}
```

Please note that if the solution is somewhat elegant the memory footprint of an *HashMap of HashMaps* have to be considered when thousands of `HashMap` instances has to be managed.

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad5e688ef41e760db1b6da7f95186abb&version=stable&mode=debug)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nicer-ish answer to this question. We can create a wrapper hash map which borrows a tuple of the keys and returns them when it doesn't need them.

```rust
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MultiKeyHashMap<K1, K2, V>
where K1: Eq + Hash,
      K2: Eq + Hash {
    map: HashMap<(K1, K2), V>,
}

impl<K1, K2, V> MultiKeyHashMap<K1, K2, V>
where K1: Eq + Hash,
      K2: Eq + Hash {
    fn insert(&mut self, k1: K1, k2: K2, v: V) -> Option<V> {
        self.map.insert((k1, k2), v)
    }

    fn contains(&self, k1: K1, k2: K2) -> (K1, K2, bool) {
        let k = (k1, k2);
        let contained = self.map.contains_key(&k);
        (k.0, k.1, contained)
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, k1: K1, k2: K2) -> (K1, K2, Option<V>) {
        let k = (k1, k2);
        let removed = self.map.remove(&k);
        (k.0, k.1, removed)
    }

    fn with_capcity(cap: usize) -> Self {
        Self{map: HashMap::with_capacity(cap)}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = MultiKeyHashMap::<String, String, i32>::with_capcity(10);
    m.insert("hello".to_owned(), "world".to_owned(), 20);
    let (k1, k2, contained) = m.contains("hello".to_owned(), "world".to_owned());
    if !contained {
        println!("failed finding key in map");
    }

    let (k1, k2, val) = m.remove(k1, k2);
    match val {
        Some(i) => {
            if i != 20 {
                println!("failed properly storing/removing value from map");
            }
        },
        None => println!("failed removing value from map"),
    }
}
```

Syntactically not super elegant but 0 cost.

If you're comfortable with unsafe:

```rust
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::mem::forget;

struct MultiKeyHashMap<K1, K2, V>
where K1: Eq + Hash,
      K2: Eq + Hash {
    map: HashMap<(K1, K2), V>,
}

impl<K1, K2, V> MultiKeyHashMap<K1, K2, V>
where K1: Eq + Hash,
      K2: Eq + Hash {
    fn insert(&mut self, k1: K1, k2: K2, v: V) -> Option<V> {
        self.map.insert((k1, k2), v)
    }

    fn contains(&self, k1: &K1, k2: &K2) -> bool {
        unsafe {
            let k1_ptr = k1 as *const K1;
            let k2_ptr = k2 as *const K2;
            let key = (k1_ptr.read(), k2_ptr.read());
            let contained = self.map.contains_key(&key);
            forget(key);
            contained
        }
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, k1: &K1, k2: &K2) -> Option<V> {
        unsafe {
            let k1_ptr = k1 as *const K1;
            let k2_ptr = k2 as *const K2;
            let key = (k1_ptr.read(), k2_ptr.read());
            let removed = self.map.remove(&key);
            forget(key);
            removed
        }
    }

    fn with_capcity(cap: usize) -> Self {
        Self{map: HashMap::with_capacity(cap)}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = MultiKeyHashMap::<String, String, i32>::with_capcity(10);
    m.insert("hello".to_owned(), "world".to_owned(), 20);
    let (k1, k2) = ("hello".to_owned(), "world".to_owned());
    if !m.contains(&k1, &k2) {
        println!("failed finding key in map");
    }

    let val = m.remove(&k1, &k2);
    match val {
        Some(i) => {
            if i != 20 {
                println!("failed properly storing/removing value from map");
            }
        },
        None => println!("failed removing value from map"),
    }
}
```