# Take element with lowest value from a HashSet?

Tags: rust, hashset

I'm trying to make a heap with a method that returns the node having the minimum `f`-value, and at the same time remove it from the heap itself.

The heap should still be usable afterwards, only without the removed value:

The `Node` struct and its implementations:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    f: f64,
}

impl Node {
    fn to_bits(&self) -> u128 {
        let xb = self.x.to_bits() as u128;
        let yb = self.y.to_bits() as u128;
        (xb << 64) + yb
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Node {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Node) -> bool {
        self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y
    }
}

impl Eq for Node {}

impl Hash for Node {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        self.to_bits().hash(state)
    }
}
```

The `Heap` struct:

```
use std::f64;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Heap {
    pool: HashSet<Node>,
}

impl Heap {
    fn add(mut self, node: Node) -> Heap {
        self.pool.insert(node);
        self
    }

    fn consume(mut self) -> Node {
      // find the node with minimum f-value in self.pool
      // and "take" it, aka remove it from the pool
      // and then return it
      Node { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, f: 0.0 } // dummy node so that the code compiles
    }
}
```

And the `main` function:

```
fn main() {
    let n1 = Node { x: 10.0, y: 11.0, f: 5.0 };
    let n2 = Node { x: 11.0, y: 12.0, f: 7.0 };
    let n3 = Node { x: 12.0, y: 13.0, f: 3.0 };
    let n4 = Node { x: 14.0, y: 14.0, f: 4.0 };

    let mut heap = Heap { pool: HashSet::new() };
    heap = heap.add(n1);
    heap = heap.add(n2);
    heap = heap.add(n3);
    heap = heap.add(n4);

    let minimal_n1 = heap.consume();
    println!("{:?}", minimal_n1);
    // should print
    // Node { x: 12.0, y: 13.0, f: 3.0 }

    let minimal_n2 = heap.consume();
    println!("{:?}", minimal_n2);
    // should print
    // Node { x: 14.0, y: 14.0, f: 4.0 }

    println!("Heap has {} nodes", heap.pool.len());
    // should print
    // Heap has 2 nodes
}
```

Here is what I've tried so far with regards to `consume`:

```
fn consume(mut self) -> Node {
    let mut min_f = f64::MAX;
    let mut min_node: Option<&Node> = None;

    for n in self.pool.iter() {
        if n.f < min_f {
            min_f = n.f;
            min_node = Some(n);
        }
    }

    self.pool.take(&min_node.unwrap()).unwrap()
}
```

The issue is that `self.pool` is borrowed immutably by the `iter()` method, and therefore the `self.pool.take()` cannot borrow it mutably at the same moment.

What would be the best approach to make this `consume` method take and return the node with has the minimal `f`-value among the `pool`?

Notes:

- a Set (or a Map) is needed because other methods need to retrieve any Node in O(1)
- I don't use an ordered set (which would easily solve the above issue) because add/update operations have to stay O(1)
- The `heap` needs to be accessed after having removed the minimum-f node, as shown in the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, since you are taking `self` by value, this is an easy problem to solve. Just throw away everything that isn't the minimum `Node`:

```
fn consume(self) -> Node {
    self.pool
        .into_iter()
        .min_by(|a, b| a.f.partial_cmp(&b.f).expect("Found a NaN"))
        .expect("There was no minimum")
}
```

If you need to keep the `Heap` afterwards, you need to disassociate the found value from the heap before removing it. Cloning is the easiest solution:

```
fn consume(&mut self) -> Node {
    let min = self.pool
        .iter()
        .min_by(|a, b| a.f.partial_cmp(&b.f).expect("Found a NaN"))
        .cloned()
        .expect("There was no minimum");

    self.pool.remove(&min);

    min
}
```

This does require that you perform an "extra" hash lookup. Since you are iterating through the entire `HashSet`, that seems like it will be a comparatively small cost.

---

If you cannot easily clone the element, buckle up. Using the ideas from [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423), we can construct a *trait object* that can be used to look up a key based on parallel but equivalent hashing / equality implementations:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Key {
    fn as_bits(&self) -> u128;
}

impl Key for Node {
    fn as_bits(&self) -> u128 {
        let xb = self.x.to_bits() as u128;
        let yb = self.y.to_bits() as u128;
        (xb << 64) + yb
    }
}

impl Key for u128 {
    fn as_bits(&self) -> u128 { *self }
}

impl<'a> Hash for Key + 'a {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, h: &mut H) {
        self.as_bits().hash(h)
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for Key + 'a {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.as_bits() == other.as_bits()        
    }
}

impl<'a> Eq for Key + 'a {}

impl<'a> Borrow<Key + 'a> for Node {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &(Key + 'a) {
        self
    }
}

impl<'a> Borrow<Key + 'a> for u128 {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &(Key + 'a) {
        self
    }
}
```

With this support, we can then convert the found element into a lightweight owned key and then look up again using it:

```
fn consume(&mut self) -> Node {
    let min_key = self.pool
        .iter()
        .min_by(|a, b| a.f.partial_cmp(&b.f).expect("Found a NaN"))
        .map(Node::as_bits)
        .expect("There was no minimum");

    let min_key: &Key = min_key.borrow();
    self.pool.take(min_key).unwrap()
}
```