# Confused by this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes but data from `key` is returned here

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
struct Key<'a> {
    key: &'a str,
}

fn get<'m, 'k, 'kr>(map: &'m HashMap<Key, usize>, key: &'k Key<'kr>) -> Option<&'m usize> {
    map.get(key)
}

fn main() {
    let map: HashMap<Key, usize> = HashMap::new();
    get(&map, &Key { key: "foo" });
}
```

gives me the following error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
8 | fn get<'m, 'k, 'kr>(map: &'m HashMap<Key, usize>, key: &'k Key<'kr>) -> Option<&'m usize> {
  |                                                            --------     -----------------
  |                                                            |
  |                                                            this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
9 |     map.get(key)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `key` is returned here
```

Yeah, `key`'s lifetimes are different from the return type's lifetime, but I don't see how "**data from `key`** is returned here" ... I see **data from `map`** returned using the key as.. well, just a key that is no longer needed after the value has been returned.

IMO, `get` should work for just any `'k` and `'kr` passed in. Returned value lifetime should be the same as `map`'s lifetime. That is what I was trying to express, but clearly my thinking is wrong somewhere..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `Key`s in your signature that should be related, but you aren't relating them. The simplest solution is to give them both the same lifetime:

```
fn get<'m, 'k>(map: &'m HashMap<Key<'k>, usize>, key: &Key<'k>) -> Option<&'m usize>
//         ^^                      ^^^^                   ^^^^
```

---

Your original code is closer to this, after lifetime elision:

```
fn get<'m, 'k, 'kr, 'x>(map: &'m HashMap<Key<'x>, usize>, key: &'k Key<'kr>) -> Option<&'m usize>
```

But I'm going to use this form instead:

```
fn get<'m, 'k1, 'k2>(map: &'m HashMap<Key<'k1>, usize>, key: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize>
```

[`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) has a non-trivial signature:

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

For example, this allows you to lookup in a `HashMap<String, V>` with either a `&String` or a `&str`.

Let's transplant that into our code and perform some substitution of generic types:

```
fn get<'m, 'k1, 'k2>(map: &'m HashMap<Key<'k1>, usize>, key: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize> {
    fake_get(map, key)
}

fn fake_get<'m, 'k1, 'k2>(_: &'m HashMap<Key<'k1>, usize>, k: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize>
where
    Key<'k1>: Borrow<Key<'k2>>,
    Key<'k2>: Hash + Eq,
{
    None
}
```

We can remove the `Hash + Eq` bound because we know it's trivially true. We can also remove the `HashMap` wrapper:

```
fn get<'m, 'k1, 'k2>(map: &'m Key<'k1>, key: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize> {
    fake_get(map, key)
}

fn fake_get<'m, 'k1, 'k2>(_m: &'m Key<'k1>, _k: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize>
where
    Key<'k1>: Borrow<Key<'k2>>,
{
    None
}
```

The error comes down to the `Borrow` trait bound — can we borrow a `Key` with an arbitrary lifetime from another `Key` with another arbitrary lifetime?

The only way for that to be true is if one lifetime is known to outlive another. This can be expressed:

```
fn get<'m, 'k1, 'k2: 'k1>(map: &'m HashMap<Key<'k1>, usize>, key: &Key<'k2>) -> Option<&'m usize>
```

> ```
> but data from `key` is returned here
> ```

I don't think this is a great error message in this case. I think it's likely that this is an uncommon case that hasn't been polished with this error message. The good news is you now have a small reproduction to file an issue with:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Key<'a>(&'a str);

fn get<'a, 'k1, 'k2>(k1: &'a Key<'k1>, k2: &Key<'k2>) -> &'a i32 {
    fake_get(k1, k2)
}

fn fake_get<'a, 'k1, 'k2>(_k1: &'a Key<'k1>, _k2: &Key<'k2>) -> &'a i32
where
    Key<'k1>: Borrow<Key<'k2>>,
{
    &42
}

fn main() {}
```

See also:

- [How to implement HashMap with two keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45786717/155423)

Comment: Aha, sure, makes sense. I've somehow overlooked that the Key in HashMap's signature also takes a lifetime parameter and the error message has mislead me down the wrong path... Thanks

Comment: OK, I've removed my Update section again, it was not relevant to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent updated answer. The Borrow obstruction has explained the need for 'k2 : 'k1 that was unclear to me. It is interesting to see that while the way `get` uses `Borrow` gives us additional power, it also puts additional restrictions on the map's and key's lifetime relationship.

In your last paragraph, do you suggest I should file an issue about the error message to the Rust team? Is this a legitimate case? I've never done that before..

Comment: Why does a `HashMap` need to borrow the key for an arbitrary lifetime? I would expect it to only need to borrow the key for as long as it takes to produce a value, which is just the body of `get()`. Once it gets the value it shouldn't need the key any longer, right?

Comment: @BallpointBen *Why does a HashMap need to borrow the key for an arbitrary lifetime?* — it doesn't and that's not what I said; I said *borrow a `Key` **with** an arbitrary lifetime* (`Key<'k1>`) not **for**. The original (incorrect) signature of `get` didn't relate the lifetime inside the `Key` held by the hashmap in the first argument and the lifetime inside the `Key` of the second argument.