# Looking up item in a hashtable where the key is a tuple which contains a non-copyable type

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a hashtable like this:

```rust
let table: HashMap<(usize, Vec<i32>), SomeStruct> = HashMap::new();
```

(in the actual application, the type is not `Vec<i32>` but is some other struct which is not `Copy`)

The key type is `(usize, Vec<i32>)`. However, if I try to perform a lookup where I only have a `(usize, &Vec<i32>)`, this is not allowed since `HashMap::get` requires `Borrow<(usize, Vec<i32>)>` which cannot be satisfied by `(usize, &Vec<i32>)`.

The context looks something like this:

```rust
fn lookup(table: &mut HashMap<(usize, Vec<i32>), SomeStruct>, index: usize, vector: &Vec<i32>) {
  // Note the 'vector.clone()' - would like to avoid doing that
  if let Some(value) = table.get(&(index, vector.clone())) { 
    // ..
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the `.clone()` when performing a lookup with this key type? I was thinking a struct wrapper type around the key type might allow me to write a custom implementation of `Borrow` but wasn't too sure if this was on the right track or how that would work.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45795699/1600898) might provide a solution, but it's more complex than I expected, and it appears to require dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Here's the issue with what you're trying to do. Imagine a tuple to be two values directly adjacent to each other in memory (this isn't always true but just assume that it is for a bit). A `(usize, Vec<i32>)` would need to be a `usize` directly followed by a `Vec<i32>`, and a reference to it would require a pointer to a region of memory that contains the `usize` followed by a `Vec<i32>`. When you just have an `&Vec<i32>`, you have a reference to a `Vec<i32>`, but there are no guarantees that there's a `usize` before it, and there's no guarantee that you can write a `usize` before it.

Comment: This leads to it being extremely difficult (basically impossible to do safely unless I'm missing something) to generate a reference to the whole tuple without cloning the `Vec` or using `unsafe` (although I don't think there's a way to use `unsafe` in a way that's not actually unsafe)

Comment: On second thought, it might be possible to use [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) in order to avoid having to clone the actual `Vec` contents.

Comment: @Aplet123 Note that the OP is willing to modify the hash map definition to use a custom type for the key. Would it be possible to define a key type that consists of `(usize, Vec<i32>)` but can be coerced to `(usize, &Vec<i32>)` for purposes of hashing and comparison? Hash maps already support something similar through `Borrow` that allows owned strings to be compared and hashed along with string slices. It seems that something similar should be possible here as well, but it's not obvious that `Borrow` allows it, except through [a trait object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45795699/1600898).

Comment: @Aplet123 I tried that out and was able to make something similar work using `std::mem::forget` and by re-constructing the type, but I wonder if there is a better solution. If we have some `x: &T`, and need to get a `y: (usize, T)`, could we do the equivalent of `memcpy(src: x, dst: y.1, size: sizeof(T))` and then not run the destructor?