# How can I remove members of a collection type in place?

Tags: rust

I want to iterate over a collection type in a struct and remove some values, but Rust prevents me from destroying the collection:

```rust
fn some_method(&mut self) {
    self.collection = self
        .collection
        .into_iter()
        .filter(/* ... */
        .collect();
}
```

I could clone all of the values to build another collection, but that's not efficient. What's the idiomatic way of removing a value from the collection in place in Rust?

Comment: What should be in `self.collection` if the `filter` callback were to panic part way through? Please provide a more complete example snippet, for instance, is `collection` a `Vec`? If it is, then `.drain(..)` instead of `into_iter()` would work here because it doesn't take ownership. There is also be `.retain(...)`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth In my case the collection is a `BTreeMap`, which doesn't have a `drain` method. Do I really need to care about panics? In rust, panics are true panics, not control flows that should be handled right?

Comment: @loganfsmyth And what I want is "remove while iterating", something like `iterator.remove()` in Java.

Comment: Probably you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913368/removing-items-from-a-btreemap-or-btreeset-found-through-iteration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing items from a BTreeMap or BTreeSet found through iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913368/removing-items-from-a-btreemap-or-btreeset-found-through-iteration)

Comment: @JiamingLu Rust's iterators can iterate over things that are immutable. Can Java's iterators do that, and if so what does `remove` do?

Comment: @trentcl java iterator.remove removes the current item. And I f you call remove on the container directly while iterating results in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A full example (also with `into_iter`):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Scores {
    collection: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Scores {
    fn new() -> Scores {
        return Scores {
            collection: Vec::new(),
        };
    }

    fn filter_in_above_50(&mut self) {
        self.collection = self
            .collection
            .drain(..)
            .filter(|score| score > &50)
            .collect();
    }

    fn filter_in_above_50_using_into_iter(&mut self) {
        let coll: &mut Vec<i32> = self.collection.as_mut();
        let coll: Vec<i32> = coll
            .into_iter()
            .filter(|score| score > &&mut 50i32)
            .map(|&mut x| x)
            .collect();
        self.collection = coll;
    }
}
```

And the tests:

```
#[test]
fn score_test() {
    let mut s = Scores::new();
    s.collection.push(199);
    s.collection.push(11);
    s.filter_in_above_50();
    assert_eq!(s.collection, vec![199]);
}

#[test]
fn score_test_using_into_iter() {
    let mut s = Scores::new();
    s.collection.push(199);
    s.collection.push(11);
    s.filter_in_above_50_using_into_iter();
    assert_eq!(s.collection, vec![199]);
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to print something in test instead of asserting?

Comment: Not really, fixed that! Thanks for highlighting :)

Comment: But `drain` only works for `Vec`, no such method for `BTreeMap` or `HashMap`

Comment: @JiamingLu, What is your case exactly?. This answer seems convenient for the Vec. If you edit the question to be more specific, you can get better and more specific answers.

Comment: @Websterix Initially I'm asking about some general patterns, no matter what type of the collection is. For example in Java, I have iterator.remove(). But now it seems in Rust there is only case by case solutions.

Comment: @JiamingLu does the second example test solves your problem? Though it works as I tested but I am interested to learn and know more about the performance impact of second approach.

Comment: `filter_in_above_50_using_into_iter` doesn't use `into_iter` on `Vec`; it just uses `into_iter` on `&mut Vec`, which is weird in a non-generic context (you could use `.iter_mut()` to be more expressive and concise). It also requires `T` to be `Copy`. In general it's just kind of weird and unidiomatic. I don't recommend writing code like that. (The `drain(..)` version looks fine though.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `collection` is a `BTreeMap` and does not have `.drain()` or `.retain`, and you're fine with emptying the tree during processing, the thing to do would be to move the tree out of `self.collection`, manipulate it how you want, and then put it back.

As you've seen, Rust doesn't allow that with simple assignment, because if there were a panic during the time when your snippet runs, `self.collection` would be left in an inconsistent state. Instead, you need to do that explicitly using [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html), which allows you to take ownership of the content in a mutable reference by providing a replacement for it, so the reference continues to point at valid data.

```
fn some_method(&mut self) {
  self.collection = std::mem::replace(&mut self.collection, BTreeMap::new())
    .into_iter()
    .filter(|_| true)
    .collect();
}
```